# Max and min with negative int input

Tags: python

I need to make a program where the user inputs 3 numbers and it prints the highest. The problem im having is if the user inputs a negative int, for example if they input 5, 9, -10, it will print -10 for the highest.

Code:

```
n1 = input(“Num1: “)
n2 = input(“Num2: “)
n3 = input(“Num3: “)

maxn = max(n1, n2, n3)

print (“Largest: “ + str(maxn))
```

Comment: Please add your code. [edit] the question and add the relevant code. Also, not if you are using Python 2 or 3. Prossibly relevant: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/20449433)

Comment: Im assuming you're not casting to an int before comparing

Comment: @JohnnyMopp n1 n2 n3 are inputs for ints then n4 = max(n1, n2, n3) and i print n4

Comment: If you include what you have so far, someone should be quickly able to help you find why sign is being ignored.  Likely a casting problem.

Comment: I added the code to the post!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a=int(input("Num1: "))
b=int(input("Num2: "))
c=int(input("Num3: "))

maxn=a

if(a>b) and (a>c):
    maxn=a

elif(b>c) and (b>a):
    maxn=b

else:
    maxn=c

print(maxn)
```

Comment: Why not just `max(a, b, c)`?

Comment: I was thinking the same @JohnnyMopp. This solution is kinda bad

Comment: max(a,b,c) is work well. Check your a,b,c is in integer or not

Comment: If it is not in integer try this max(int(a),int(b),int(c)) because if it is string it compare with - mark as char

Comment: You must put this three input numbers into a list in order to be able to perform max()

Comment: @Osakr No. There are 2 versions of the `max` function. One that takes an iterable and one that takes an variable number of args. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: Thx, didn't know ^^

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is based on list sorting. The user input is added to a list and the list is sorted.

```
inputs = list()

inputs.append(input('Number #1:'))
inputs.append(input('Number #2:'))
inputs.append(input('Number #3:'))
max_number = sorted(inputs)[-1]
print('Max number: {}'.format(max_number))
```